# Delaying JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

On my webpage I have a piece of javascript that allows a div to fade in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#page_effect').fadeIn(10000);

    });
</script>
```

But, I would like the same div to fade out. I have the code for the fade out but I'm wondering how I would delay the javascript code from running, for about 140 seconds

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#page_effect').fadeOut(140000);

    });
</script>
```

Comment: So you want the page to load, it wait for 140 seconds then fade out? Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('#page_effect').fadeOut();
        }, 140000);
    });
</script>
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/76E6E/) is a test fiddle with a smaller delay (so that you don't have to wait for the full 140 seconds of course)

More info on `setTimeout` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout)

Another option would be to use jQuery's `.delay()` method, referenced [here](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

Try reading about setTimeout http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you.. use set interval for you function [set interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery you can use the .delay() method. Have a look at the documentation and you'll find an example too.

https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `setTimeout();` like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

   setTimeout(function(){ $('#page_effect').fadeOut(140000);},140000);

});
```

This run fadeout after 140 sec if you want reverse then use callback of fadeOut like this

```
 $('#page_effect').fadeOut(140000,function()
   {alert("I will be called after 140 sec")}
 );
```